# Eloquent query so slow in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I'm doing an application in Laravel 5.3.19, the thing is, I'm doing a query with Eloquent but it is SO slow, I read some forums and seems like I'm doing something wrong, I tried doing this query in the console with the command `php artisan tinker` and the query work perfectly, the problem is when I log into the URL that I created in the `routes/web.php` from my browser, the page just load indefinitely and sometimes It gives to me a timeout error. Someone knows what could be the problem?

here are my files:

- routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/area_products/listProductsByArea/{area}','AreaProductController@orderProductsListByArea');
```

- Http/controllers/AreaProductController.php (Controller)

```php
public function orderProductsListByArea($area){
    $array_products = [];
    $products = AreaProduct::where('area_id', $area)->get();
    foreach ($products as $data) {
        $product = [
            'id' => $data->id,
            'price' => $data->price,
            'product_id' => $data->product->id,
            'product_name' => $data->product->name,
            'product_category' => $data->product->category->name,
            'product_reference' => $data->product->reference,
            'product_code' => $data->product->code,
            'area_id' => $data->area_id
        ];
        array_push($array_products, $product);
    }
}
```

- Http/AreaProduct.php (Model)

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class AreaProduct extends Model{
    public $table = "products_area";
    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
    public function area(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Area');
    }
}
```

Note: This query should return near to 700 results, I noticed the problem is produced when I'm doing the relations stuff like `'product_name' => $data->product->name`. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `foreach ($products as $data) {`, your code will see places.. such as timeouts.. since you are using **Lazy Load** mercilessly. you should change `$products = AreaProduct::where('area_id', $area)->get();` to `$products = AreaProduct::where('area_id', $area)->with('product')->get();` to Eager Load the relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Eloquent relationships can't you just do this:

```
public function orderProductsListByArea($area){
    // Load the Area products with the 'product' relationship (eager loading)
    $products = AreaProduct::where('area_id', $area)
        ->with('product')
        ->get();

    // Return the list of products
    return $products;
}
```

Without seeing the rest of your data/db, I'm pretty sure that should return what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! it doesnt even take 2 seconds in the query, again, thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed